# Redux actions always in pending state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a scraping application using redux toolkit for learning purposes.Whenever I dispatch the action the data gets scraped and console logged but the action state is never fullfilled and is always pending

MY ASYNC THUNK

```
export const loadData = createAsyncThunk(
  "alldata/getdata",
  async ({ pageNo, language }, thunkAPI) => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/scrape?pageNo=${encodeURIComponent(
        pageNo
      )}&language=${encodeURIComponent(language)}`
    );
const res=await data.json()
    return {
      payload: res,
    };
  }
);
```

MY SLICE

```
const projectSlice = createSlice({
  name: "allprojects",
  initialState: {
    projectState: [],
    workingState: [],
    isLoading: false,
    hasError: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProject: (state, action) => {
      return state.workingState.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeProject: (state, action) => {
      return state.workingState.filter(
        (project) => project.link !== action.payload.link
      );
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [loadData.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.hasError = false;
    },
    [loadData.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.projectState = payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.hasError = false;
    },
    [loadData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;

      state.hasError = true;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProject, removeProject } = projectSlice.actions;
const Projectreducer = projectSlice.reducer;
export default Projectreducer;
export const projectSelector = (state) => state.allprojects;
```

REACT COMPONENT

```
const { workingState, projectState, isLoading, hasError } =
    useSelector(projectSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [selectData, setSelectData] = React.useState({ languages: "" });
  const [pageData, setPageData] = React.useState({ pageNo: 1 });

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      loadData({ pageNo: pageData.pageNo, language: selectData.languages })
    );
  };
```

[image]
So how do I get the action to be fullfilled and push the data in the ProjectState array after the async request

EDIT:
API

```
app.get("/scrape", async (req, res) => {
  const { pageNo, language } = req.query;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    `https://github.com/search?p=${pageNo}&q=language%3A${language}`,
    {
      waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    }
  ); // URL is given by the "user" (your client-side application)
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const list = [];
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".repo-list-item");
    for (const item of items) {
      list.push({
        projectName: item.querySelector(".f4 > a").innerText,
        about: item.querySelector("p").innerText,
        link: item.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"),
      });
    }
    return list;
  });
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
});
```

Store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import Projectreducer from "./Slices/slice";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    allprojects: Projectreducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: `data.json()` returns a Promise. You should await it

Comment: still action is in pending state

Comment: It is possible to have a code sandbox with a reproductible example ?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the api that you are fetching is throwing an error so in this case it always recommended to have a catch block and throw an error to that its falls into `loadData.rejected` state.

So, do the check network tab in the dev tools of the browser that you are using, so that you can confirm if the api is responding or not.

Also can you share the `projectSelector` selector ? could be the something wrong in the selector.

action:

```js
export const loadData = createAsyncThunk(
  'alldata/getdata',
  async ({ pageNo, language }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const data = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/scrape?pageNo=${encodeURIComponent(
          pageNo
        )}&language=${encodeURIComponent(language)}`
      );
      const res = await data.json();
      return {
        payload: res,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue({ payload: error?.message || error });
    }
  }
);
```

reducer:

```js
  extraReducers: {
    ...,
    [loadData.rejected]: (state, {  payload }) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.hasError = true;
      state.message = payload;
    },
  },
```

---

One more thing to mention here is that redux toolkit recommends to use `builder callback`, for more details check here:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#extrareducers

in your example it would be like

```js
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadData.pending, (state) => {
       ...
      })
      .addCase(loadData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
       ...
      })
      .addCase(loadData.rejected, (state, action) => {
       ...
      });
```

Comment: The api is responding well as I am able to see the response in the console